# What would this guy/woman mean in a line by a phrase "to avoid cherrypickers" in a context?

Tags: word-meaning

I made [**a question at History**](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/51416/has-anyone-recently-seen-chinese-old-customary-greeting-pose/52065#52065) about a month ago.

And I received a new answer ( the second one ).

In that, he/she says,

> Although most people don't care about it too much nowadays, still it is very hard to avoid **cherrypickers** nowadays. So if you prefer to keep it simple and afraid of making mistakes, JUST SHAKE HANDS, it's much easier that way.

What would it mean? ( [**There seems to be no appropriate definition according to my dictionary.**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cherry_picker) )

> 1 A piece of equipment consisting of a large basket at the end of an extensible boom, often mounted on a truck body, and used by workers to reach inaccessible places such as power lines and tall trees.
>
> 2 A person or group that picks the best for themselves; one who cherry-picks.
>
> 3 A person or group that picks only evidence which supports an argument and ignores evidence which contradicts it; one who cherry-picks.
>
> 4 A person or device that harvests cherries, or that aids in the harvesting of cherries.

Probably I guess he would mean something by the definition of 2?

But I'm afraid I don't understand what he/she would mean by "to avoid cherrypickers" in this context.

Comment: I just read that answer and I still can't tell you what that person meant. Maybe ask in a comment there?

Comment: I read through the q&a and have no idea what the person could mean. I suggest you comment on the answer and ask. If I had to make a guess, I think definition 2--people who consider themselves "better" so they'll use the traditional way rather than use the Western custom of shaking hands.

Comment: The use of that word in that sentence and context makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: You might specifically ask if it's possible they meant nitpickers? It comes after a description of how complicated and detailed the salutation is depending on who's doing it and for what purpose, and how many people no longer care, but some still do. They may have meant that some people would find fault no matter how you do it.

Comment: @Katy ahh..."nitpickers" makes sense. I will ask him. Thanks.

Comment: vtc as probably an error, as in comments above.

Comment: Close? What on the earth is the reason?

Comment: If this is just a mistake by someone else, using the wrong word, then there is not question that can be answered. We can't tell you what "cherrypickers" means in this context because it means nothing.  If a question can't be answered it should be closed. I'd upvote and close because the question is good but it doesn't need to be here.  If you have asked and found that nitpickers is correct or not, you could edit that information in.

Comment: Looking at the linked question, the guy edited to change cherrypickers to nitpickers, so this question can be removed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it cannot be answered here as the question arose from a mistake on the History site which has now been resolved. The author meant "nitpicking".

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all of you at the comment line for all the advice.

Thanks to James K, I haven't noticed that the original answerer made a correction and as many had guess it, it was not "cherrypickers" but "nitpickers".

Thank you again. However, though it is O.K to close this question, **at that time** it was hard to choose where to ask because the original answerer did not respond to my comment and nobody understood what "avoiding cherrypickers" might mean then.

Anyway, thanks.